# How to show different images from one image on your webpage

Tags: image

Can any one tell me how to show image of Facebook, Google, etc. on different positions from this image-[image: The image]

to something like this-[image: 2]: ![Result image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is called an image "sprite." It is a collection of images put into a single image.

You have to use CSS to choose which portion of the "sprite" file should be displayed. Check out this link from W3 schools for usage examples:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

for the top most image

```
#topimage{
  background-image:url('/images/image.png');
  background-position:0 0;
  width:200px;
  height:24px;
}
```

for the second image from top,
assuming the height of the each part of image to be 24px..

```
#secondimage{

background-image:url('/images/image.png');
background-position:0 -24px;
    //-24px means the picture is shifted up by 24px so 
    //that the second image from top is visible
width:200px;
height:24px;
}
```